# $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_nx^n=1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+7x^5+11x^6+\cdots$ and $Q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q_nx^n.$ What is $\dfrac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Let
$$P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_nx^n=1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+7x^5+11x^6+\cdots$$
be the partition generating function, and let $Q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q_nx^n$, where $q_n$ is the number of partitions of $n$ containing no $1$s.

Then $\dfrac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ is a polynomial. What polynomial is it?

---

What should I do?  Should I plug the $P(x)$ into $Q(x)$?  I'm a mess here, solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I imagine $p_n$ are the prime numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Formally, we have
$$P(x) = \prod_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{1-x^k}$$
(see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Generating_function)). Can you do something similar for $Q(x)$?

Comment: I believe you can rewrite $Q(x)$ as $(1-x)P(x),$ so the answer would be $1-x,$ am I correct?

Comment: @Regina Yes, that is correct.